# BIOS update doesn't change anything

Tags: bios

I'm trying to update the BIOS on Lenovo ThinkCentre M58p which shows a BIOS date of 05/07/2012. When I boot from CD with the iso file it asks whether I want to update the serial number and model type. After that it begins the procedure of updating and everything seems like it well. But after saying that the update was successful and restarting into BIOS, no new settings appear and the BIOS date remains the same. Upon trying to boot from CD the second time however, after the serial and model questions I'm warned that BIOS on the CD is a lower version or the same as the BIOS installed. Even after the second try it all remains the same.

Comment: What makes you think new settings should appear?

Comment: Hi John - the ISO image you mention, is that created using this link which supposedly contains BIOS version 
5CKT77A > https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_bios/5cjz77usa.exe

Comment: No, it's from this link https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/thinkcentre_bios/5cj977a.iso

Comment: I saw a video which had the boot option for legacy and uefi, which is what I am looking for. The BIOS date on that video is newer than mine but older than the download.

Comment: @John - You want the .exe instead of the .ISO

Comment: The .exe did not nothing when I tried using it

Comment: I'm sorry, the .exe file did copy the files to the default destination, I just never checked there. There is an image file and a folder with other files, however. Do I need any of those files?

Comment: The file the .exe contained and the one I had downloaded previously are the exact same size, so does the .exe really make a difference? Or are the other files important?

Answer (score 0):

Version 5CKT77A, dated 05/07/2012, is the latest version of the BIOS. Lenovo updated the release date on their download page http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds013586 from 5/16/2012 to 6/2/2015, but without changing any of the actual files. You can verify this by looking at old snapshots of the page on the Wayback Machine at archive.org.

Comment: Please don't use answers for discussion, that's what comments are for. I've rolled back your edit. Downvoters: please explain what's wrong with this answer so that it can be improved.

Comment: Sorry for not using a comment, I originally tried to add a comment to the question but couldn't due to not having reputation points. My edit was to point out that the OP mistakenly believed that a BIOS update existed, but it doesn't, so he's not actually updating, just rewriting the same BIOS (probably due to being misled by Lenovo's incorrect 2015 release date). Of course nothing will change.

Comment: Lenovo has now fixed their site to indicate that the actual 5CKT77A release date was 5/15/2012.